# Getting no Response when i click on item in ListView in my fragment

Tags: android

I have a list view in one fragment and when I click on item in the `ListView` that should be navigated to another activity related to the selected option, but in my case it is not happens and also it is not throwing any error also.. it is clickable but it is not navigating.

//***My Fragment Class***//

```
 package com.cityzers.welcometohyderabad;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 * Created by DELL on 04-03-2018.
 */


public class TouristPlace extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    public ListView list;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    public TextView tv;
    public Statement statement;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tourists, container, false);
        list = rootView.findViewById(R.id.places);
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/Welcome_to_hyd", "root", "test");
            statement = con.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        final String[] placelist = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, placelist);
        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView text=(TextView)view;
        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                String Fort="Select Description from testHyd where TouristPlace='Golconda'";
                try {
                    ResultSet result= statement.executeQuery(Fort);
                    while (result.next()){
                        String Desc=result.getString(2);
                        Intent i=new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),ListNavigation.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        i.putExtra("description",Desc);

                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();;
                }


        }
    }
}
```

///***This is the activity to display after navigation***///

```
package com.cityzers.welcometohyderabad;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 * Created by DELL on 10-03-2018.
 */

public class ListNavigation extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.placesoutput);
        TextView tv=findViewById(R.id.hydtext1);
        tv.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("description"));
    }
}
```

///***LogCat***////

```
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.ResultSet java.sql.Statement.executeQuery(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
03-21 15:57:39.828 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at com.cityzers.welcometohyderabad.TouristPlace.onItemClick(TouristPlace.java:57)
03-21 15:57:39.828 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
03-21 15:57:39.828 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1156)
03-21 15:57:39.828 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3121)
03-21 15:57:39.829 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4048)
03-21 15:57:39.829 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3807)
03-21 15:57:39.829 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10023)
03-21 15:57:39.829 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2626)
03-21 15:57:39.829 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2307)
03-21 15:57:39.835 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
03-21 15:57:39.842 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
03-21 15:57:39.842 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
03-21 15:57:39.843 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
03-21 15:57:39.844 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
03-21 15:57:39.844 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
03-21 15:57:39.857 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
03-21 15:57:39.857 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
03-21 15:57:39.858 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
03-21 15:57:39.858 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
03-21 15:57:39.858 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
03-21 15:57:39.858 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
03-21 15:57:39.859 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
03-21 15:57:39.859 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
03-21 15:57:39.859 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
03-21 15:57:39.859 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
03-21 15:57:39.860 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:413)
03-21 15:57:39.862 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1808)
03-21 15:57:39.862 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3061)
03-21 15:57:39.862 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
03-21 15:57:39.862 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:375)
03-21 15:57:39.863 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10243)
03-21 15:57:39.863 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4438)
03-21 15:57:39.863 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4306)
03-21 15:57:39.864 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
03-21 15:57:39.864 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
03-21 15:57:39.864 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3872)
03-21 15:57:39.864 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3999)
03-21 15:57:39.865 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
03-21 15:57:39.865 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4056)
03-21 15:57:39.865 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
03-21 15:57:39.865 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
03-21 15:57:39.866 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3872)
03-21 15:57:39.866 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
03-21 15:57:39.866 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
03-21 15:57:39.866 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6246)
03-21 15:57:39.866 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6220)
03-21 15:57:39.867 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6181)
03-21 15:57:39.867 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6349)
03-21 15:57:39.867 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
03-21 15:57:39.868 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
03-21 15:57:39.868 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
03-21 15:57:39.868 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-21 15:57:39.868 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
03-21 15:57:39.869 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-21 15:57:39.869 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
03-21 15:57:39.870 3147-3147/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: try by passing getApplicationContext() as a 1st argument in intent.

Comment: it is not even suggesting the getApplicationContext() method and even i wrote it.. it is shwoing error

Comment: please post logcat here

Comment: sorry for the late response, im  facing issue with my android studio Emulator.. even though it have emulator it is still showing emulator is not installed

Comment: i tried the query in mysql and it return me the output, but here it is return nullpoint exception

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),ListNavigation.class);
 i.putExtra("description",Desc);
 startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
Intent i=new Intent(view.getContext(),ListNavigation.class);
i.putExtra("description",Desc);
startActivity(i);
```

> Always add the the `putExtra` before `startActivity(i);` you are adding after `startActivity(i);`

else

```
 tv.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("description"));
```

in other activity will crash because `getIntent().getStringExtra("description")`
is **Null**

Answer (score 0):

You are opening your activity inside while loop, so if your `result.next()` is false it will not open it's it true it will try to loop continuously so it will not open.

Try to get the proper value from resultset and try to open outside the while loop it will work fine.

Comment: i tried in that way also but still getting same result

Answer (score 0):

Please make few changes:- Use correct `context`

replace this line

```
list = rootView.findViewById(R.id.places);
```

with

```
list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.places);
```

This line

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, placelist);
```

with

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, placelist);
```

This line

```
Intent i=new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),ListNavigation.class);
```

with

```
Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),ListNavigation.class);
```

And also remove this line

```
TextView text=(TextView)view;
```

Comment: remove this line  TextView text=(TextView)view;

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();;
}
```

you catched Exceptions, so was there any log?